# Highlight significant coefficients in coefplot

Tags: r

Is there a way of changing the colour, to red say, of *only* significant coefficients on the `coefplot` plot?

For example (plot 2 in coefplot's helpfile),

```
require(coefplot)
y1 <- rnorm(1000,50,23)
y2 <- rbinom(1000,1,prob=0.72)
x1 <- rnorm(1000,50,2) 
x2 <- rbinom(1000,1,prob=0.63) 
x3 <- rpois(1000, 2) 
x4 <- runif(1000,40,100) 
x5 <- rbeta(1000,2,2) 

longnames <- c("a long name01","a long name02","a long name03",
               "a long name04","a long name05")

fit1 <- lm(y1 ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5)

# plot 2
longnames <- c("(Intercept)", longnames) 
coefplot(fit1, longnames, intercept=TRUE)
```

Comment: I dont think there is a straight forward way to do this. Have a look at `buildPlotting.default`; this maps colour (and shape and linetype) to `"Model"` variable [see output of `coefplot.default(fit1, intercept=F, plot=F)`] and see only one factor in "Model"  hence only one colour. A quick work around is to define your own `buildPlotting.default` with colour mapped to a new variable indicating significant coefficients.

Answer (score -1):

You don't necessarily need to do that even though it would be nice...If the coefficient plot's 95% confidence interval stretches past zero on either side, then it is not significant at the 5% level.  Vice versa, if it does not, then it is statistically significant from 0 at the 5% level.  Hope that makes sense!